# NSData not accepting escaped / UTF8 encoded URL

Tags: ios, nsurl

I am trying to create an NSData object that contains the contents of a file in my main bundle.

```
NSString *chordPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:chordName ofType:@"png"];

NSURL *chordURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[chordPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *chordImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:chordURL];
UIImage *chordImage = [UIImage imageWithData:chordImageData];
```

Prior to using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` I was getting a nil URL, so I went ahead and fixed that by reencoding the string. Now I get a valid URL but the `chordImageData` object is nil for me. The file is definitely included in my main bundle (since I was able to get the URL to begin with) so I am wondering what's wrong.

EDIT:

Running this:

`NSData *chordImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:chordURL options:NSDataReadingMapped error:&dataCreationError];`

Gets me this for the error:

```
po dataCreationError
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x7530a00
```

Looking around Google it seems that the URL is still not encoded correctly. Anyone know an additional step to make sure the encoding is valid?

Comment: You can check if any errors occurred when getting the data via `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`.

Comment: Yup just did that, error posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using fileURLWithPath:, something like this:

```
NSString *chordPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:chordName ofType:@"png"];

NSURL *chordURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: chordPath];
NSData *chordImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:chordURL];
UIImage *chordImage = [UIImage imageWithData:chordImageData];
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need to do percent escaping. The reason you're having problems is that you are using `URLWithString:` which is meant for "non-file" URLs.

You should use [`+fileURLWithPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJBGFBJ) for file-based URLs:

```
NSString *chordPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:chordName ofType:@"png"];

NSURL *chordURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:chordPath];
NSData *chordImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:chordURL];
UIImage *chordImage = [UIImage imageWithData:chordImageData];
```